# LINQ compound select problem

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble getting a LINQ compound select to compile. Here is the code:

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

var pairs =
    from a in numbersA,
            b in numbersB
    where a < b
    select new {a, b};
```

The code is from a tutorial from here, under the heading 'SelectMany - Compound from 1':

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758.aspx#SelectSimple1

And the compile-time error i get is as follows:

A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

The comma just after 'numbersA' is where the error occurs.
Now i can't figure out what i've done wrong, since this is just code as per the MS website. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Thank you for asking exactly what I was going to ask this minute :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is not a valid LINQ expression. `from` clause supports a single collection only. You should repeat the whole `from` clause. You probably meant to say:

```
var pairs = from a in numbersA
            from b in numbersB
            where a < b
            select new {a, b};
```

Comment: You got here first :) I'm voting you up.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and it works great. Pity that the MS site has invalid code!

Answer (score 10):

The equivalent fluent syntax using [SelectMany](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/SelectManyOperator.ashx), just for the record:

```
var pair = numbersA.SelectMany(a => numbersB, (a, b) => new {a, b})
                   .Where(n => n.a < n.b);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your intent correctly, then you need another from.

Like this:

```
var pairs =
    from a in numbersA // Comma removed from end of line here
    from b in numbersB // additional "from" keyword at start of line
    where a < b
    select new {a, b};
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Sorry though, mehrdad got in first with the answer